# how to solve a system of Ordinary Differential Equations (ODE's) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode

I have to solve a system of ordinary differential equations of the form:

```
dx/ds = 1/x * [y* (g + s/y) - a*x*f(x^2,y^2)]
dy/ds = 1/x * [-y * (b + y) * f()] - y/s - c
```

where x, and y are the variables I need to find out, and s is the independent variable; the rest are constants. I've tried to solve this with ode45 with no success so far:

```
y = ode45(@yprime, s, [1 1]);

function dyds = yprime(s,y)
    global g a v0 d
    dyds_1 = 1./y(1) .*(y(2) .* (g + s ./ y(2)) - a .* y(1) .* sqrt(y(1).^2 + (v0 + y(2)).^2));
    dyds_2 = - (y(2) .* (v0 + y(2)) .* sqrt(y(1).^2 + (v0 + y(2)).^2))./y(1) - y(2)./s - d;
   dyds = [dyds_1; dyds_2];
return
```

where  @yprime has the system of equations. I get the following error message:

> YPRIME returns a vector of length 0, but the length of initial
>   conditions vector is 2. The vector returned by YPRIME and the initial
>   conditions vector must have the same number of elements.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: My bet would be that at least one of `g`, `a`, `v0`, or `d` remain uninitialized, thus `[]`. Using these "coefficients" will yield an empty vector for `dyds`. You could test this with `assert(~isempty(v0), 'v0 not initialized')` in `yprime`.

Comment: Your equations are singular.  You are dividing by x, but your initial condition is x = 0.  I don't know if this is the source of your error, but it will be a problem.

Comment: By the way: It is not best practice to use global variables here. For transfer of Parameters with ode45 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215121/matlab-for-loop-within-ode-solver/29219310#29219310

Comment: thanks pal , that's certainly helpful  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, you should have a look at your function `yprime`. Using some simple model that shares the number of differential state variables with your problem, have a look at this example.

```
function dyds = yprime(s, y)
    dyds = zeros(2, 1);
    dyds(1) = y(1) + y(2);
    dyds(2) = 0.5 * y(1);
end
```

`yprime` must return a column vector that holds the values of the two right hand sides. The input argument `s` can be ignored because your model is time-independent. The example you show is somewhat difficult in that it is not of the form dy/dt = f(t, y). You will have to rearrange your equations as a first step. It will help to rename `x` into `y(1)` and `y` into `y(2)`.

Also, are you sure that your `global g a v0 d` are not empty? If any one of those variables remains uninitialized, you will be multiplying state variables with an empty matrix, eventually resulting in an empty vector `dyds` being returned. This can be tested with

```
assert(~isempty(v0), 'v0 not initialized');
```

in `yprime`, or you could employ a debugging breakpoint.

Comment: You were right they were empty. Now it works and I get the value of both variables, but I get this error message: ??? Error using ==> odearguments at 113
YPRIME must return a column vector....

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for ODE solvers is `[s y]=ode45(@yprime, [1 10], [2 2])`

and you dont need to do elementwise operation in your case i.e. instead of `.*` just use `*`[image: y(:,1) plotted against s with initial conditions [2 2] and parameter values: g=1;a=2;v0=1;d=1.5;]

[image: y(:,2) vs s]

Comment: i tried and it just worked.. just didnt know suitable values for your global variables... it works fine..

Comment: well in your equation there is a division by s; so you cannot start s from 0. just missed it.. and perhaps thats why you are getting NaN or something

Comment: Thanks bharat_iyengar. The values of the global variables are vectors of 1x100, so that's why I used the .*, otherwise it will say: "??? Error using ==> mpower
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix"