# matlab for loop within ode solver

Tags: matlab, ode

i am using ODE solver for solving my system of ODE. Now i also want to calculate sensitivity of various parameters by varying them. 
My basic ODE solver program is something like:
Function:

```
function F = ODE_site(t,y)
%%Parameter block
k1f=1e8;
k1b=1e5; %%and so on

%%Elementary rate block
r1=k1f*y(1)-k1b*P*y(5);
and so on

%%Mass balance block
F=[  r1-r5-r78+r86 ;
    and so on ];
%% End of function
```

The main ODE solver looks like:

```
optode = odeset('NonNegative',1:41,'Abstol',1E-20,'RelTol',1E-20);
y0=zeros(41,1);
y0(41) = 1;
[t,y]=ode15s(@ODE_site,[0,50000000000],y0,optode);
%% Plus some other lines to plot the solution
%% End of ODE solver
```

Now, I want to introduce a for loop in the main solver but the problem is if i use for loop in the main solver, it cannot pass the command to the function. I tried to use global to assign the variable to all over the environment but it didn't work. How can i assign the for loop for both the ODE solver code and function?
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Mamun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the parameters, which you want to modify as addional input parameter to the function:

```
function F = ODE_site(t,y,param)
%%Parameter block
k1f=param(1);
k1b=param(2); %%and so on

%%Elementary rate block
r1=k1f*y(1)-k1b*P*y(5);
and so on

%%Mass balance block
F=[  r1-r5-r78+r86 ;
    and so on ];
%% End of function
```

You can hand over the parameters to your function in ode15() after the optimisation Parameters:

```
optode = odeset('NonNegative',1:41,'Abstol',1E-20,'RelTol',1E-20);
y0=zeros(41,1);
y0(41) = 1;
para=[1e5, 1e8]
[t,y]=ode15s(@ODE_site,[0,50000000000],y0,optode,para);
```

Two notes:

*) Code is untested. Since your example was not executable I didn't care to make a running example too.

*) It looks like you are solving chemical reaction kinetics. Most likely you could further optimize your code by using matrix and vector operations.
So instead of usning separate variables `r1, r2, r3,` .. you could store it in one vector `r(1), r(2), r(3),` ...
Your last line, than could be written by the product of the reaction vector with the stoechiometric matrix.

Comment: Thank you!!!  Now, it is working fine. I will try to use your suggestion to save on time.

Comment: FYI, in current versions of Matlab (the past ~10 years), `[t,y]=ode15s(@(t,y)ODE_site(t,y,para),[0,50000000000],y0,optode);` would be the preferred, non-deprecated, means of passing parameters. Using an anonymous function as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) like this may also yield faster code.

Comment: Thank you horchler for this hint.